# Is it possible to enter "real" fullscreen on displays other than display 0?

Tags: sdl, fullscreen, sdl-2

In my SDL2 program, I would like to enter fullscreen, but I'm on a desktop with multiple displays and I would like to enter fullscreen on any specific display.

*I know this can be done with* `SDL_SetWindowFullscreen(window, SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP)`.

*However*, I want to use `SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN` (without `_DESKTOP`), instead. The reason is that it has less latency. But when I do that, it will enter fullscreen on display 0 *exclusively*, even if the window was on another display when I called the function.

Can I use `SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN` on other displays, or is it strictly limited to display 0? I am doubtful because `SDL_SetWindowFullscreen` does not take an argument specifying which display to pick. Is that maybe why the other fullscreen mode is called `_DESKTOP`? Thanks.

---

Here's a little more context, if you like.

- I am using Windows 10, though I don't think that matters much.
- I am using SDL `2.26.2`,  but I've used the same code with an older
  dll (`2.0.16`) and had the same issue.

#### Why `FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP` is slower, and I would rather use `FULLSCREEN`

`FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP` is a kind of "fake" fullscreen which is really just a resized window positioned perfectly, so it takes up the whole screen, whereas "real" fullscreen actually changes the video mode of the display. It says so in the docs for [SDL_SetWindowFullscreen](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_SetWindowFullscreen#remarks).

> SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN, for "real" fullscreen with a
> videomode change;
>
> SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP for "fake" fullscreen
> that takes the size of the desktop;

As such, I've noticed that both windowed and fake fullscreen (which we know now are essentially the same thing) have a little more latency than real fullscreen. I made a little sprite that follows my cursor, and it lags behind noticeably more in fake fullscreen than it does in real fullscreen. Presumably because fake fullscreen still renders the desktop behind it and real fullscreen does not.

Comment: Looking at SDL source code, it should work if you set your window position to be at desired display, or by passing `SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED_DISPLAY(display_index)` to `SDL_CreateWindow`. Displays could be enumerated via `SDL_GetNumVideoDisplays`/`SDL_GetDisplayBounds`. Native fullscreen mode allows you to change display resolution and bypass compositing system. Sometimes it is desired, sometimes far less so.

Comment: @keltar You are right about passing the display index to SDL_CreateWindow. If I initialize the window on display 1, native fullscreen will be tied to display 1. So it is possible! But dragging the window around after the fact doesn't change to which display it is tied. Even if I check with `SDL_GetWindowDisplayIndex` to make sure that SDL understands I dragged the window to another display, entering native fullscreen will again go back to the display on which I initialized the window.

Comment: Could you check if you get event with type `SDL_WINDOWEVENT` and `event.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_DISPLAY_CHANGED` when you move window to another monitor? What's your SDL version?

Comment: @keltar I do get the event when I drag the window to my other monitor, and as I said before polling with `SDL_GetWindowDisplayIndex` tells me it is on the other display. But entering native fullscreen goes back to the display on which the window was first opened. When going fullscreen, the display index of the window does not update. If the window was on display 1 and it goes to fullscreen on display 0, the display index of the window remains 1. It's completely aware of on which display the window is, native fullscreen just doesn't seem to use that value.